# not able to generate Rds Iam Auth Token using aws cpp sdk

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-cpp

We need to generate an aws rds iam auth token using the c++ sdk.

Java sdk equivalent is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.AuthToken

Is there a way to do the above using the C++ SDK?

The following code just results in printing the connection string (replace parameters with actual values):

```
Aws::RDS::RDSClient* p = new  Aws::RDS::RDSClient();
std::cout << p->GenerateConnectAuthToken("host", "region", 3306, "user");
```

Not sure if these are related:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/868

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/864

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the returned token? Sounds like it returning a url is the expected behaviour

Comment: What is 868, 864?

Comment: AWS documentation for RDS: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/aws-cpp-sdk-rds/html/class_aws_1_1_r_d_s_1_1_r_d_s_client.html#ae134ffffed5d7672f6156d324e7bd392

Comment: updated 864 and 868 in question @kiner_shah

Comment: Hi @AlanBirtles, wont it return a token to be used as password? could you point to any documentation for usage?

Comment: The url is the token (from reading the issues you've linked to)